# Selectively remove files and folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a batch script that takes value from reading an input file and correspondingly  deleting those folder contents but skipping the last 5 items on it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%x in (sample.txt) do (
  set folder=%%x
  set del_folder=D:\myfolder\work\!folder!\reports
REM !del_folder!
    FOR /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a IN (' DIR !del_folder! /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q "echo Deleting folder contents of !del_folder!\%%a"
 )
```

sample.txt looks like ( it contains the folder names)

```
alpha
bravo
charlie
tango
...
```

1. How can I exclude bravo and tango from the loop
2. For the remaining folders i.e. alpha and charlie, how can I exclude specific folders or files on inside the target folder

Example,

say folder `'java'` and a file `'report.yml'` located under `D:\myfolder\work\alpha\reports` has to be excluded from getting deleted

same goes for `D:\myfolder\work\charlie\reports`

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To exclude some folders in Sample.txt file, change this line:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%x in (sample.txt) do (
   ```

   to

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%x in ('findstr /v /c:"folder 1" /c:"folder 2" "sample.txt"') do (
   ```
2. To exclude some files inside `!folder!\reports`, change this line:

   ```
   FOR /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a IN (' DIR !del_folder! /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q...
   ```

   to

   ```
   for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in ('dir !del_folder! /o-d /b^|findstr /v /c:"string 1" /c "string 2"') do del /q /f "%~fa"
   ```

Just edit `folder 1`, `folder 2`, `string 1`, and `string 2` for your purposes. This is untested so comment if there are problems.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply, can you please explain the section - `"%~fa"` and `/b^|`

Comment: I'm facing the below issue

`FINDSTR: /c ignored
FINDSTR: Cannot open classpath-term.yaml`

classpath-term.yaml is the only file in that folder

Comment: Oops... It should be `%%~fa` instead of `%~fa`. From `FOR/?` documentation, `%%~fa` expands `%%a` to a fully qualified path name. Then, in `/b^|`, `/b` is still your `dir /b`, and the `^|` is just an escaped pipe, which is somewhat required inside IN clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot Poypoyan for the explanation, I get the below error when I try to match classpath-term.yaml file on the folder. 

I used `findstr /v /i /r /c:"classpath-term.yaml"` DO I have to escape the hyphen on the string ?

Comment: I saw the source of your (or rather, **my**) error: just change `/c "string 2"` to `/c:"string 2"`. **Edit:** no need to escape the hyphen.

Comment: I have used `/c:"classpath-term.yaml"` still its unable to locate the file and its giving `FINDSTR: /c ignored FINDSTR: Cannot open classpath-term.yaml`

Am i missing something silly? thanks again for your help here. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Now, that's weird. Is the problem only on that long FOR loop? Try replacing that with this: `for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in ('dir "!del_folder!" /o-d /b ^|findstr /i /v /c:"classpath-term.yaml"') do del /q /f "!del_folder!\%%~nxa"` if this still didn't work, chat is needed.

Comment: SOrry for the delayed reply, It worked, really thanks a lot for all your help here !!!!